# Setting paragraph indentation AND vertical space in KOMA class

Tags: spacing, indentation, koma-script, paragraphs

I would like to have both a paragraph indentation and a vertical space between paragraphs in a the KOMA article class.

At the moment I use `\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14, parskip=half]{scrartcl}`
to have vertical spacing, but I do not know how can I also have indentation.

Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Your unusual request can be solved by `\setlength{\parindent}{0.5em}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add somewhere in your preamble

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
```

you get what you want. You can change the indentation when you input another value for the length.

See this minimal example, which by the way also shows, that you could change the `\parindent` length later in the document, as well.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,DIV=14,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\verb|\parindent| \texttt{obviously 0pt:}

\kant[10]

\kant[20]

\verb|\setlength{\parindent}{1em}:|
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\kant[30]

\kant[40]
\end{document}
```